# Adding -fopenmp to program using Eigen causes linker error

Tags: c++, openmp, linker-errors, eigen, eigen3

I've written a small program (about 200 lines) in C++ that involves Eigen computations, as well as Eigen's unsupported tensor library. I'm getting a linking error when I compile with -fopenmp using GCC, after having modified include/define statements following the [recommendations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) in the Eigen docs. The text of the error is...voluminous, but it looks like within the Eigen internals it's unable to find a definition for the function `omp_get_max_num_threads` whilst linking.

```
/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: mytool.cpp:(.text._ZN5Eigen8internal16parallelize_gemmILb1ENS0_12gemm_functorIdlNS0_29general_matrix_matrix_productIldLi0ELb0EdLi0ELb0ELi0EEENS_5BlockINS5_INS_3MapINS_6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEELi0ENS_6StrideILi0ELi0EEEEELin1ELin1ELb0EEELin1ELin1ELb0EEESD_SD_NS0_19gemm_blocking_spaceILi0EddLin1ELin1ELin1ELi1ELb0EEEEElEEvRKT0_T1_SK_SK_b[_ZN5Eigen8internal16parallelize_gemmILb1ENS0_12gemm_functorIdlNS0_29general_matrix_matrix_productIldLi0ELb0EdLi0ELb0ELi0EEENS_5BlockINS5_INS_3MapINS_6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEELi0ENS_6StrideILi0ELi0EEEEELin1ELin1ELb0EEELin1ELin1ELb0EEESD_SD_NS0_19gemm_blocking_spaceILi0EddLin1ELin1ELin1ELi1ELb0EEEEElEEvRKT0_T1_SK_SK_b]+0x2b1): undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads'
```

This gets printed to the terminal multiple times (not character for character the same but similar) before the linker gives up and halts.

When compiled without this flag, no error is produced and the code runs (single threaded) as expected. I'm trying to include the openMP parallelization because I thought that matrix products were parallelized if this compiler flag was added.

I used `#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS` before including the tensor libraries, and I included `<Eigen/Core>` first above all the other eigen modules. I also call `setNbThreads(nthreads);` where nthreads is an int, after command line parsing. Finally, if it matters, I am performing matrix operations with a `MatrixXd::Map` rather than a simple matrix, because I used the tensor library to work with more indices before reducing to a 2-Tensor, which I then mapped onto a `MatrixXd`.

Happy to provide more information as needed.

Comment: This error tells you that the linker fails to find the requested `omp_get_max_num_threads ` symbol which indicates that you didn't provide the right library during the link stage.

What are you using to compile your program?

Comment: Do you pass `-fopenmp` to the linker as well?

Comment: @ThomasCaissard I am using scons, because this program is built as a stand-alone binary from a larger collection of software for analysing molecular dynamics trajectories. Scons is using the version of g++ that comes with conda-forge's x86_64 build system for gnu linux.

Comment: @chtz This suggestion cleared up the issue. If you want to make an answer out of it I'd accept it, though I understand it is not Eigen-related. It turns out that `-lgomp`, which I'd found somewhere else, doesn't work.